# Как добавить программу в автозагрузку используя WinAPI (C/C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

Какая функция, описание которой находится в заголовочном файле `windows.h` (насколько я знаю, она там), отвечает за автозапуск и как прописать, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
HKEY hKey; 
char szPath[0x100]; 
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, sizeof(szPath)); 
RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
                 "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 
                 NULL, 
                 "", 
                 REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, 
                 KEY_SET_VALUE, 
                 NULL, 
                 &hKey, 
                 NULL);

if (hKey) 
{ 
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, "My program", NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, strlen(szPath)); 
    RegCloseKey(hKey); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за все ответы

Answer (score 11):

Функции Windows API за автозагрузку не отвечают. За автозапуск отвечает запись в реестре в ключах (Local Machine или Current User)

> `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`

Прописывается

1. вручную в редакторе реестра,
2. запуском файла с нужными записями реестра *.reg,
3. во время установки,
4. с помощью [функций работы с реестром](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875(v=VS.85).aspx).