# Добавление в- и удаление из автозагрузки

Tags: c++

Как (в С++ Builder 6) добавить приложение в атозагрузку для текущего пользователя при соблюдении некоторого условия, к примеру а==б, и удалить приложение из автозагрузки при а!=б.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить в приложение в автозагрузку, нужно прописать ключи в реестре

> `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
>   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce`

```
if (a == b)
    // Прописываем ключи
else
    // Очищаем ключи
```

Подробнее: [автозапуск программы при включении компютера C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/31679/%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-c).

Comment: Было бы подробнее, если бы код был с комментариями. желательно, чтоб описывалось за что отвечает каждый параметр, и даже если станет ясно как ключи прописать, все равно остается вопрос как их очистить. И кроме того, как я писал в самом вопросе, "для текущего пользователя". То есть, наверное, вместо HKLM следует использовать HKCU?

Comment: По поводу ключей реестра - [Описание разделов реестра Run, RunOnce, RunServices, RunServicesOnce и Startup](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365/ru)

Comment: Это тоже не совсем то, что мне нужно. Я постараюсь предельно ясно свормулировать свой вопрос. Меня интересует пример кода, желательно с комментариями, которым можно удалить программу из автозапуска. Как добавить в автозапуск я не то чтобы хорошо понял, но научился делать, спасибо userx'у за ссылку.