# Как добавить программу .exe в автозагрузку через c++

Tags: c++, winapi

Сразу говорю, это не кейлоггер и не вирус, просто пишу программу для автоматизации некоторых действий у себя на компе. Я знаю что чтобы добавить программу в автозагрузку нужно взаимодействовать с регистром, но на его изучение, к сожалению, пока нету времени. Кто может подсказать как это реализовать на c++?

Я что-то слышал, что надо использовать `IsMyProgramRegisteredForStartup(PCWSTR pszAppName)`, `RegOpenKey`, `RegSetValueEx`, но я точно не знаю как с ними правильно взаимодействовать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065/how-to-read-a-value-from-the-windows-registry
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/31679/Как-добавить-программу-в-автозагрузку-используя-winapi-c-c

Comment: если речь идет об ОС семейства Windows 98 и старше, то можно воспользоваться файлом c:\autoexec.bat (эх молодость, молодость ;)