# Нужна помощь с автозагрузкой программы в С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, автозапуск

Я написал небольшую програмку на С++ в Visual Studio 2019
Вопрос: как программно сделать так что бы эта программа сама добавлялась в автозагрузку?
Можно ли пожалуйста привести код? Желательно с комментариями)
Или же хотя бы ссылку на внятный гайд))

Comment: [Работайте с реестром.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/32002/463167) Подобное решение уже было написано.

Answer (score 4):

1. определяете полный путь к вашей программе
2. добавляете соответствующую запись в [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run] или [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]

Comment: я же спросил как программно выполнить что бы сама добавлялась через код

Comment: вам и отвечено как. дальше уже детали. будете вы это делать с использованием winapi https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions или будете использовать более высокоуровневые вещи. решать вам